# Is this (Hibert-Schmidt) integral kernel bounded?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, compact-operators

It is well known in the theory of bounded operators on $L_2(\mathbb{R}, \mu)$ that the operator
$$ Tf(x) = \int_\mathbb{R} k(x,y) f(y) \: dy  $$
is compact whenever $k(x,y) \in L_2(\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R})$. In my case I have the integral kernel,
$$k(x,y) = e^{10x^2 - (x - \frac{1}{2}y)^2/2x^2}.  $$
I wish to show that this $k(x,y) \in L_2(\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R})$. The measure, $\mu$, on my space is an intractable stationary distribution, but it decays on the order of $x^{-1/2}$ away from $0$. Is there a way to determine whether or not $T$ is indeed Hilbert-Schmidt for this $k$? What about if decay is of the order $x^{-1/2}e^{-hx}$?

I have attempted to use Schur's test, but I cannot find functions $p(x),q(x)$ which would give me a result here. Perhaps a clever choice could do the trick? I think that due to the slow rate of decay, $k$ probably not bounded.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: You have a term $e^{10x^2}$, thats going to grow much faster than anything else in the exponetial and cannot be compensated by a $x^{-1/2}$ decay. Youve got no chance for it to be in $L^2$!

Comment: Yeah, wishful thinking by me. Haha Thanks!